# Storing sessions in database with TTL Expiry.

Tags: mongodb, scala

The constraints:

- Load balancing environment, sessions need to be persistent across servers.
- OAuth 2.0 provider/authentication, tokens are created/refreshed quickly.

Storing sessions/tokens in the DB was the logical move.

1. Is this the standard practice?
2. Is this the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [TTL index on a collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) like `db.sessions.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )`. This will create a collection with elements TTL equal to one hour. After a hour is gone, Mongo will automatically remove stale entries. Replication is also supported!

I do not know much about storing sessions in DB (I'm working with application servers that handle sessions for me) but I know that some simple frameworks (like bottle or flask for python) use this practice.